Plotly, Quarto, RevealJS
I used to use plotly slides in HTML based Rmarkdown documents.  Is this no longer a feature for RevealJS Quarto documents?
---
title: "Untitled"
format: revealjs
editor: visual
---

## Plotly Issue 

Here is my plotly slide

```{r, echo = F, warning=FALSE, comment=F, message = F,  fig.width=8, fig.height=3}
library(plotly)

y <- rnorm(100)

plot1 <- plot_ly(
          x = 1:100,
          y = y, 
          type = 'scatter',
          mode = 'lines')%>%
          layout(showlegend = F)
plot1
```

The code above creates the issue. This is the error I am getting


It doesn't work.  I have updated a picture of the error message.

Please don't post pictures of error messages, post it as code formatted text.

@kpr62 This should work. Make sure you have updated to the latest Quarto version. What version are you using?
